# VC++ 2010 Syntax Highlighting vs. VC++ 2008 Syntax Highlighting: Tab Character Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2008

Visual C++ 2010 has some sort of weird syntax highlighting issue when it comes to tab characters inside comments, and I know this is a trivial issues, but it's driving me crazy. I'm going to have to show you some screenshots so you will understand what I mean...

This is in Visual C++ 2010 Express
[image: This is in Visual C++ 2010 Express]

Same thing pasted in Visual C++ 2008 Express
[image: Same thing pasted in Visual C++ 2008 Express]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in Visual Studio 2010 and the 2011 preview.

To reproduce:

```
Tools->Options->Fonts And Colours->Comments
Item Background -> Purple/Red/Blue/Anything
```

The only solution was to change the back colour of all text (Plain Text), which I don't think you wanted to do or to go back to 2008 Express

Comment: Correct, I like for my comments to have a different background color than the Plain Text or Code.

Comment: I've spent a significant amount of time trying to find a solution to this. While, I'm not happy that the answer seems to be "Don't use a different background color," it does seem to be the only answer.